# Allow only numeric values in TextField

Tags: nativescript

How can I restrict the input in a TextField only to numeric values? An often suggested recommendation/solution for that is to set keyboardType property to 'number', however that does not work on iOS. I still can enter any character in the TextField.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be listening to `textChange` event and overwrite any non-numeric characters in the text, something like

```
function onTextChange(args: PropertyChangeData) {
    let value: any = parseFloat(args.value);
    if (isNaN(value)) {
        value = '';
    } else {
        value = value.toString();
    }
    if (value != args.value) {
        const object = <any>args.object;
        object.text = value;
        if (object.android) {
            object.android.setSelection(value.length);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=TptOfV)

Comment: This looks like a hack and not a solution. Post-editing of already allowed and shown value.

Comment: That was the intension, a cross platform hack. But even if you prefer to use the exact native solution, the logic is more or less the same. Override the [textFieldShouldChangeCharactersInRangeReplacementString](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/text-field/text-field.ios.ts#L75) delegate callback and filter the non-numeric characters from input.

Comment: UITextFieldDelegateImpl is private. I didn't find any way to override one of it's functions. Doing it dynamically on _delegate property has no effect.

Comment: You can't just override a function in the delegate instance as it's a native object, you will have to implement your own delegate similar to that, modify the particular method as you need.

Comment: Seems creating a completely new own delegate implementation is the only way to do it. what a pain...

Comment: @Gamadril. What did you end up doing? I also don't like the masked plugin because it's buggy.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS this may be of use: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-numeric-keyboard - it's a plugin that changes the keyboard into a strict numeric one, and you get to tweak a few of its features as well.

Comment: I did a quick test of the plugin. The software keyboard has changed, but I still can enter all characters from the hardware keyboard and also copy & paste any text...

Comment: I was talking about usage on a real device. Not a sim.

Comment: Me too, bluetooth keyboard and pasting per long touch context menu.

Comment: That's a hardware keyboard, right? The plugin is for giving you a numeric soft keyboard, not to prevent entering other characters through external means. So I guess you'll need a "text change" listener on the input and filter out any irrelevant characters that way.